# Filtering image in a way as in overlay apps

Tags: ios, swift, filtering, core-image, chromakey

I am creating an application to give the functionality of overlay as in photoshop.

I have two images,

1. The background image on which the overlay would be added,
2. The Foreground image to which the filtration will be applied

**Note:** Both the images are in .jpeg format

I tried to use the Chroma Key effect, but it has some smoothness issues and not working properly on different color removal.

[This is the image after applying the ChromaKey effect by removing black color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNCGR.jpg)

The above image has smoothness issues

[There are images like this also when I try to remove its background color, it doesn't work properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukxf1.jpg)

How can I achieve this functionality

Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a blend mode, specifically `CIOverlayBlendMode`. You can find [more about this in the relevant docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIOverlayBlendMode)

Comment: hey, @Alladinian thanks for the response! Currently, I am busy at some work, will let you know after trying this one. But, I have a question that will this work well on .jpeg images because the foreground image is not transparent on which the filtering will be applied.